# OpenGl does not display triangles using VBO

Tags: opengl, maya, vbo

I am trying to display 2 simple triangles in OpenGL, but they don't appear, despite checking numerous sites. Did I forget anything in the code ?

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(bytes) ((GLubyte*) NULL + (bytes)) 


    // Prepare:
    GLfloat vertices[]={0,0,1,
        0.5,0,-0.5,
        0,0,0,
        0,0,1,
        0,0,0,
        -0.5,0,-0.5};
    GLushort indices[]={0,1,2,3,4,5};

    GLfloat *generatedVertices=new GLfloat[18];
    GLushort *generatedIndices=new GLushort[6];
    GLfloat *colors=new GLfloat[18];

    glGenBuffers( 3, triangleBuffers ); // triangleBuffers = Global GLuint

        for (int p=0;p<6;p++)
        {
            MVector V(vertices[p*3],vertices[p*3+1],vertices[p*3+2]); // Maya type
            generatedVertices[p*3]=V.x;
            generatedVertices[p*3+1]=V.y;
            generatedVertices[p*3+2]=V.z;

            generatedIndices[p]=p;

            colors[p*3]=0.8f;
            colors[p*3+1]=0.6f;
            colors[p*3+2]=0.0f;
        }


   // vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*18, generatedVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*6, generatedIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // couloirs
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*18*data->totalSize, colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

---

```
    // Render:
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[1]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data->triangleBuffers[2]);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0,  BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, totalSize*6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
```

Comment: You upload indices in `GLushort` format, but in the draw call you say it is of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` format.

Comment: What is the camera's position set at? If it has a position of `0` on the `y-axis` then that means, based on your vertices. You wouldn't see the triangles because you're drawing the two triangles flat. Try the following vertices;

`0,1,0 - 0,0,0 - 0.5,-0.5,0` For triangle one

Comment: BDL: Good catch, corrected but still displaying nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is coming from maya. In OpenGL-Legacy mode, the mesh is properly displayed, in OpenGL-Strict mode, it isn't. I will investigate in this direction.